# Alternative to ui:include for dynamically including pages in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

Before I start:  I'm running JSF 2.0 MyFaces on Tomcat 6 and I've used some primefaces in this project already.

I've got a page with three filtered dropdowns that set a bunch of parameters in my backing bean.  These parameters are then used to include a page under the dropdowns.  I'm using ui:include to include this page but I'm pretty sure that ui:include only executes once per lifecycle.  That means that the page shows up once and does not change when the dropdowns change.

Here is an example of my view

```
<h:form>
    <!-- dropdowns to build the route to the included page -->
    <h:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItems ... />
        <f:ajax 
           event="change" 
           render=":formInclude" 
           execute=":formInclude" 
           listener="#{control.handledd1Change}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItems ... />
        <f:ajax 
           event="change" 
           render=":formInclude" 
           execute=":formInclude" 
           listener="#{control.handledd2Change}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItems ... />
        <f:ajax 
           event="change" 
           render=":formInclude" 
           execute=":formInclude" 
           listener="#{control.handledd3Change}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
<h:panelGrid id="formInclude">
    <ui:include src="#{control.formName}.xhtml"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

So, I was wondering what the most correct way of dynamically including a page in JSF is.  Am I correct about the ui:include only executing once?  Is there anything else out there that I could use to dynamically include a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I was able to get ui:insert to execute after each drop down change.  All I had to do was execute and re-render it using ajax.  This was the page that I used to help find my way:

[How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Comment: Could you provide @Dave example how use ui:insert to change content based on drop down changes? Thx.